# using wildcards in a windows .bat file to find two files and run a command on both at the same time

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to run an exe on two files both of which I need to use wildcards to get the name.

myprogram.exe *keyword*.txt W*.txt

putting that command in a .bat file only causes the file name to used literally with * in the name.

Comment: Run `help for`, take a look at the `for /f` command.  Now the question is do you really have to run every `*keyword*.txt` against every `W*.txt` file?  Is there a natural pairing?

Answer (score 0):

I created the following files in a test directory:

- 1keyword2.txt
- 1keyword3.txt
- W1.txt
- W2.txt

Wrote the following test script:

```
@setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
@set prompt=$G

@for %%a in (*keyword*.txt) do @call :DoIt %%a
@exit /b 0

:DoIt
@for %%A in (W*.txt) do @echo myprogram.exe %1 %%A
@exit /b 0
```

Which yields the following results:

```
> test
myprogram.exe 1keyword2.txt W1.txt
myprogram.exe 1keyword2.txt W2.txt
myprogram.exe 1keyword3.txt W1.txt
myprogram.exe 1keyword3.txt W2.txt
```

The first for loop, loops over all the `*keyword*.txt` files in the current directory and calls :DoIt on each result value, then :DoIt loops over each `W*.txt` file in the current directory, yielding every combination of `*keyword*.txt` and `W*.txt`.  Just remove the `echo` command and change `myprogram.exe` to whatever your program name is and it should work you.

NOTE: I always call out to a subroutine for non-trivial work in the body of a `for/do` loop.  It avoids lots of potential pitfalls involving multiple line code blocks (in parens) and issues with delayed/immediate expansion of variables.  Makes life easier when debugging problems.